# How can I use dynamic variables with anonymous types?

Tags: dynamic-expresso

I am trying to use dynamic variables containing anonymous types. For example:

```
var hello = new { french = "bonjour" };
// alternative, dynamic hello
// var hello = new ExpandoObject();
// hello.french = hello

dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.a = hello;

// alternative, anonymous x
// var x = new { a = hello };

Assert.AreEqual("bonjour", x.a.french); // Sanity check - never fails

var interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.SetVariable("x", x);

var result = interpreter.Eval<string>("x.a.french"); // fails
Assert.AreEqual("bonjour", result);
```

However, I get the error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does
>   not contain a definition for 'french'

So apparently, x.a does not have the correct type?
If I introduce a named class, Translate, and change the first line to

```
var hello = new Translate {french = "bonjour"};
```

it works as expected. It also works if I replace make both x and hello anonymous by replacing lines 2 and 3 with

```
var x = new { a = hello };
```

or if I make both x and hello dynamic.

If I make x anonymous and hello dynamic, it also fails:

```
    dynamic hello = new ExpandoObject();
    hello.french = "bonjour";
    var x = new { a = hello} ;
```

Here, I get the error

> DynamicExpresso.Exceptions.ParseException: No property or field
>   'french' exists in type 'Object'

Is there any way to make my first code sample work? In real life, I am trying something somewhat more complex.

I also have problems trying to access arrays:

```
dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();

dyn.Foo = new int[] {42};
var interpreter = new Interpreter()
            .SetVariable("dyn", (object)dyn);

Assert.AreEqual(dyn.Foo[0], interpreter.Eval("dyn.Foo[0]"));
```

Comment: Try to look here: https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/blob/master/test/DynamicExpresso.UnitTest/DynamicTest.cs Consider that this works only on .NET 4.7 and with version 1.3 or later

Comment: Thanks - 4.7 is fine. I've taken a look, but I still cannot make it work. For example, adding this test fails (sorry about the missing formatting)


    [Test]
    public void Get_Property_of_a_nested_Anonymous()
    {
        dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
        dyn.Sub = new { Foo = "bar"};

        var interpreter = new Interpreter()
            .SetVariable("dyn", dyn);

        Assert.AreEqual(dyn.Sub.Foo, interpreter.Eval("dyn.Sub.Foo"));
    }

Comment: I have tracked it down to Parser.ParseDynamicProperty - apparently it chooses the "wrong" binder? This is probably due to the two-pass approach - first we parse and type-analyse the code, then we run it. During parsing we decide that the type of dyn.Sub is object and generate a binder based on that?

Comment: Uhm yes, probably this is not supported. Can i ask you to open an issue with your unit test and the current SO link? Thanks

Comment: I have created two issues - one for the anonymous class issue, one for indexers. Do you have any tips for workarounds? I wouldn't mind writing my own DynamicObject-derived class, but I would really like to support expressions like myObject.dynamicName.someProperty[1]